# Big O derivation of validation estimate

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

[image]

I have a question regarding the last line in this slide, taken from the free "Learning From Data" course, lecture 13 on validation. [here is a link to it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7zzaKd0Lkk&t=782s)

At start,I was not familiar with this $O()$ notation. After doing some research in wikipedia and youtube, I have an intuitive understanding of what this line means:

the error in the validation set is approximately the error in the all of the sample space, with an error that scales by $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{K}}$ when we increase $K$.

But I still lack the ability to derive $O(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{K}})$ from the third line and the expression $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{K}$, in a way that one would have done it without looking in the solution first.

So, can anyone share the way he would develop the fourth line from the third one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the variance of a random variable $X$ is the average squared distance between $X$ and its mean $\mathbb{E}(X)$. That means that the average (unsquared) distance will be on the order of $\sqrt{\text{var}(X)}$. In this case, the random variable is not $X$ but $E_{\text{val}}(h)$. Since
$$
\text{var}[E_{\text{val}}(h)] = \frac{\sigma^2}{K},
$$
on average the cross-validation error will be a distance of roughly $\sigma/\sqrt{K}$ away from its expected value of $E_{\text{out}}(h)$. Since we are interested in how this measure of precision changes with the size $K$ of the validation set, we drop the constant $\sigma$ and write $O(1/\sqrt{K})$ instead.

Stepping back, what Professor Abu-Mostafa is saying here is that we can expect the cross validation error to be reasonably close to the out-of-sample error. How close exactly? Well as we increase the size $K$ of our validation set, we can expect the gap between the validation error and the out-of-sample error to be on the order of $1/\sqrt{K}$.

Answer (score 1):

If ${\rm var} X =\frac{1}{K}$ then, by the Chebyshev inequality,
$${\bf P}\left(|X-{\bf E}X|>\frac{z}{\sqrt{K}}\right)\le 
\frac{K\ {\rm var}X }{z} = \frac{1}{z}.
$$
That is what the professor means, $\sqrt{K}|X-{\bf E}X|$ may be stochastically bounded by some random variable, which does not depend on $K$.